# Print JQplot in new window

Tags: printing, jqplot, new-window

I open my JQplot on a modal Div window, which has a print button.

I want the print button to only print the graph.

Or possibly open a new window with a graph in it.

What do you think is the best route and how would that solution work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call something like this thats inside of an onclick

```
//if the print button is in parent window   
$("#iframe")[0].contentWindow.window.PrintFrame();

//runs in child frame
function PrintFrame() 
{
     //hide everything you don't want to see besides the graph
     window.focus();
     window.print();
}
```

I would not open a new window.

Just create an anchor tag with an onClick event. Inside the event hide everything you don't want and then fire window.print(). Another way would be to create a print style sheet and hide everything you don't want to show up in the print style sheet.

[How does this print stylesheet work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914190/how-does-this-print-stylesheet-work)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Amil. Well i am kinda doing the same BUT
The problem is that my graph gets generated on the fly through javascript. So it doesnt get generated when i pass the content into a new window. :(

Comment: In that case cant you just use a css print style sheet? Or you could remove all the dom items besides the graph and call windows.print() on a click event like I described above. Does that answer your question?

Comment: kinda.. but not entirely... as i have to show the user wats gona get printed. thats y we have this new window in which we show wat and  how is ur print gona look like..

well i had to call the graph function again in the new window so that it cud print it... and it got resolved :)

Comment: Alright gotcha. So did my answer help you solve your problem? If so please mark it as the answer! Thanks man