# Restricting certain elements from being printed

Tags: css

I am trying to only print certain elements with JavaScript. For example, when a link is clicked it will open the print dialog window. However, I wish to have some elements of the table not printed and for the headers to be on one line instead of breaking into multiple lines.

[image: Printing Elements]

I want to get rid of the Edit and Delete table cells and put all the table headers on one line. Here is my current JavaScript code I have in place:

```
$('#print').on('click', function() {
    var content = document.getElementById("sample_editable_2");
    var holderWindow = window.open("");

    holderWindow.document.write(content.outerHTML);
    holderWindow.print();
    holderWindow.close();
});
```

Sorry if this is unclear, I've never attempted this before.

Appreciate any help that can be given.

- Edit:

Here is my css file

```
 @media print {
    .h_edit {
        display: none;
    }

    .h_delete {
        display: none;
    }

    .b_edit {
        display: none;
    }

    .b_delete {
        display: none;
    }

    .order-issue {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .sub-shipping-issue {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .sub-refunds-returns-issue {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .sub-update-issues {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .sub-campaign-issues {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .sub-campaign-change-issues {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .sub-campaign-design-issues {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .sub-teeforall-works {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .order-id {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .site-url {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

and I am calling the css file like so: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" href="/css/print.css">`

but it is still not hiding the elements and making them not wrap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914190/how-does-this-print-stylesheet-work is the way probably

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand how this is related to javascript. For you to control how pages are printed, you need to write a css file for print only. Something like

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />`

Then in `print.css` you should do

```
.print-hide {
   display: none; // or whatever you want
}
```

Any item with `.print-hide` will be treated with above CSS.

Comment: How would I exclude certain table td cells though, that is what I am trying to do. Here is my css file:  
 @media print {
 #sample_editable_2 {
  display: none;
 }
}

Comment: @user2101411 - To hide the edit and delete columns see: [show/hide html table columns using css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858339/show-hide-html-table-columns-using-css). Simply adapt that answer to the print media.

Comment: I only want to hide it on the print dialog. I don't understand how that link relates to my question.

Answer (score 1):

To complete [Amir Raminfar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35259576/1428679), for your second request

> and for the headers to be on one line instead of breaking into multiple lines

you can add to the same "print-only" CSS a directive to get some items to not go next line. Be aware that this could wreck the page layout, when the whole table has to be redesigned.

```
.print-one-line {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

So:

```
<td class="print-hide">This won't appear</td>
<td class="print-one-line">This will not go on the next line</td>
```

To verify it is working, you can check the CSS console and use [Media Type Emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519556/faster-way-to-develop-and-test-print-stylesheets-avoid-print-preview-every-time) if available in the browser.

Comment: Would using @media print { } be required?

Comment: Absolutely. You want those lines to kick in only when you're *printing*, not when the media type is *screen*. Or you do as Amir suggested and prepare two CSS, one loaded with media="print".

Comment: I used white-space: nowrap; but it is still showing on two lines?

Comment: @user2101411 - Inspect which css attributes are actually being applied to the element using the browser developer tools (F12). Ensure that nowrap is being applied as you expect.

Comment: I referenced them all via classes. Why would it not be applied? (see my css code if that helps)

Comment: Added to answer. Don't know why it wouldn't be applied, but apparently it is not. What you're doing is correct. There must be something else preventing the CSS from being loaded and/or applied. Possibly caching?

Comment: cleared my cache but it still is showing the same way. I don't know why.. :\